# How can I fill a date input with Laravel Dusk?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-dusk

I try to fill a `date` input with Laravel Dusk with this code:

```
$browser->type('cooked_at', (new Carbon())->format('Y-m-d'));
// ...
```

But I get this error:

> Element must be user-editable in order to clear it

Every other input fields are OK. Just the one with type `date` fails.

How can I fill a date input with Laravel Dusk?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/104 Also, in 5.5 you can do `now()->toDateString()` instead of `(new Carbon())->format('Y-m-d')`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Ok thanks! you can post this as an answer and I will accept it! (or if you prefer I can post the answer myself)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/104), you have to do something like:

```
$today = now();
$browser->keys('#cooked_at', $today->day)
        ->keys('#cooked_at', $today->month)
        ->keys('#cooked_at', $today->year);
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a quick tip for those out there who tries to test an `<input type="date">` field with Laravel Dusk.

`->type('#cooked_at', '2022-01-01')` doesn’t work the way you expect, but this does:

```
$browser->keys('#cooked_at', '2022', '01', '01', '{tab}')
```

Or you can pass date like

```
$today = now();

$browser->keys('#cooked_at', $today->year, $today->month, $today->day, '{tab}')
```